# Unique workspace directories for build executors

Tags: jenkins

I've got a Jenkins instance running with multiple build executors.

All of which have the workspace in /tmp/workspace.

I've got a new build executor and I want it to have the workspace in a different location. (somewhere with a little more space).

Comment: Do you need to build the Workspace in different folder?? or do you need a single job to run on different workspace.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar I need to have all builds that are built on this one build executor instead of building in /tmp/workspace build in /mnt/workspace

Comment: You can configure the path at  Manage Jenkins ->Configure System you can change Home Directory Path, in which the workspace will build.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar That's a global variable though, I just want this one specific build executor to use the different workspace.

Comment: In job Configuration we have an option called 'Use custom workspace'. where you set the path for that particular Job to execute. This option is present in 'Advanced' option.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
At this option you can configure your path of executing the job for that particular job. At Directory you can set the path.